# Inheriting parent theme styles in a child theme on Wordpress Multisite

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

I'm having an issue inheriting a parent themes styles using a child theme on a multisite install of Wordpress. Basically the parent theme has been created using FoundationPress and I've written a script to automatically create a child theme when a new multisite/blog is created. This works fine and creates the correct styles.css and, I thought, the correct functions.php file. I have the following in my functions.php in the child theme:

```
wp_enqueue_style('first-stylesheet', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/split/foundation_split_1.css', array(), AD_VERSION );
```

The issue I'm having is that `get_template_directory_uri()` is returning the domain with the virtual domain appended, eg. http://example.com/test-site/wp-cont... which is not the correct url for the parent themes style sheet (it should be http://example.com/wp-cont...).

Any body have any idea what I'm doing wrong? Is this a rewrite I need to configure server side?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I missed something some rewrites in my nginx configuration. For anyone having similar problems the crucial lines are:

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
    rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/wp-.*) $1 last;
    rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/.*\.php)$ $1 last;
}
```